# Automating subtitle extraction with ruby and mkvextract

Tags: ruby

Awhile ago I managed to hack together a script in ruby which would look into a folder and extract subtitles from all .mkv files contained within.

However, my computer since crashed and I had to reinstall ruby, now I tried it again and it doesn't seem to be working for me, not sure If I had an older version of my script or what.

here's the code

```
path = ARGV[0]
Dir.chdir(path)
filename = "#{path}#{Dir.glob("*.mkv").first(1)[0]}"
puts filename

Dir.glob("#{path}*.mkv"). each do | mkv_path |
mkv_name = File.basename( mkv_path, ".*" )
extract_command = `mkvextract tracks #{mkv_path} #{2}:#{mkv_name}.srt`
puts "#{mkv_name}"
end
```

and I have ruby installed and mkvtoolnix obviously. not sure about the environment variables for mkvextract though, perhaps that's the problem? I'm on windows 10.

Anyway I just run it by opening up command prompt, going to the dir and typing:

```
ruby SRTextractor.rb {e:\test}
```

(test being the folder it's in, SRTextractor.rb being the script)
If my mkv is named movie it returns this in the console

```
e:/testmovie.mkv
```

but does not create the SRT file. I'm not sure if that's an error with the filename or it's meant to look like that. If someone could help me with how to get it going would be greatly appreciated, thanks!.

Comment: Be really careful when passing in shell arguments like that. It's always best to use [`shellescape`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.5/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-shellescape) on any argument as they might contain shell characters (e.g. `[`) or spaces which can mess up your arguments.

Comment: Is this an issue with slash versus backslash? Internally Ruby can deal with either, but some Windows tools cannot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's script example I wrote to extract the subtitle srt from a few mkv's I downloaded. I tested it on my Raspberry Pi, still works

```
ARGV.each do |extract|

mkvfile=File.basename(extract, ".mkv")

#using system command get information from mkv container using mkvinfo
system "mkvinfo ""\"#{mkvfile}.mkv\""""

puts "enter a track ID"
#get the track ID
track_id=STDIN.gets.chomp

#using system command extract .srt file using track ID specified using mkvextract
system "mkvextract tracks ""\"#{mkvfile}.mkv\""" #{track_id}:""\"#{mkvfile}.srt\""""
end
```